# Alternative to Stream_Copy_To_Stream() php

Tags: php, memory, upload, stream, copy

I am working on a file sharing site right now and I've run into a small problem. I am using the upload scrip uploadify which works perfectly but if the user wants i want the uploaded file to be encrypted. Now i have working code that does this as shown below but my server only has 1GB or memory and using stream_copy_to_stream seems to take up the size of the actually file in memory and my max upload size is 256 so i know for a fact that something bad is going to happen when the site goes live and multiple people upload large files at once. Based on my code below is there any alternative that barely uses and memory or none at all, I wouldnt even care if it takes longer i just need this to work. I have the download version of this working because i have the file directly decrypted and immediately passed through to the browser so it decrypts as it downloads which i though was pretty efficient but this upload problem doesn't look to good. Any help is appreciated.

```
$temp_file = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $new_file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $target_file = rtrim(enc_target_path, '/') . '/' . $new_file_name . '.enc.' . $ext;

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = substr(md5('some_salt' . $password, true) . md5($password . 'more_salt', true), 0, 24);
    $opts = array('iv' => $iv, 'key' => $key);

    $my_file = fopen($temp_file, 'rb');

    $encrypted_file_name = $target_file;
    $encrypted_file = fopen($encrypted_file_name, 'wb');

    stream_filter_append($encrypted_file, 'mcrypt.rijndael_128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
    stream_copy_to_stream($my_file, $encrypted_file);

    fclose($encrypted_file);
    fclose($my_file);
    unlink($temp_file);
```

temp_file is the first instance that i can see of the uploaded file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and good to know what to do when i find a solution.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have better results if you try reading the file in chunks like this?:

```
$my_file = fopen($temp_file, 'rb');

$encrypted_file_name = $target_file;
$encrypted_file = fopen($encrypted_file_name, 'wb');

stream_filter_append($encrypted_file, 'mcrypt.rijndael_128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
//stream_copy_to_stream($my_file, $encrypted_file);

rewind($my_file);

while (!feof($my_file)) {
    fwrite($encrypted_file, fread($my_file, 4096));
}
```

You might also try calling [`stream_set_chunk_size`](http://php.net/stream_set_chunk_size) prior to calling `stream_copy_to_stream` to set the size of the buffer it uses to read from the source stream when copying to the destination.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:  I tested with this code and when uploading a 700MB movie file, the peak memory usage of PHP is 524,288 bytes.  It looks like `stream_copy_to_stream` will try to read the entire source file into memory unless you read it in chunks passing the length and offset arguments.

```
$encrypted_file_name = $target_file;
$encrypted_file = fopen($encrypted_file_name, 'wb');

stream_filter_append($encrypted_file, 'mcrypt.rijndael_128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);

$size = 16777216;  // buffer size of copy
$pos  = 0;         // initial file position

fseek($my_file, 0, SEEK_END);
$length = ftell($my_file);    // get file size

while ($pos < $length) {
    $writ = stream_copy_to_stream($my_file, $encrypted_file, $size, $pos);
    $pos += $writ;
}

fclose($encrypted_file);
fclose($my_file);
unlink($temp_file);
```

Comment: Hi something weird happened, I created the file and everything but the file has Zero bytes (empty) so im not sure what happened.

Comment: Hi i figured out the problem i had to change the fwrite file from encrypted_file_name to encrypted_file and yes this did work for a 23 mb file upload it only used about 13 mb of memory. Im still paranoid about reaching my memory limit, is there anything else i can do to have almost a zero kb memory footprint?

Comment: Good catch, sorry for my error :)  13MB is pretty far from your memory_limit of 256M.  I'm not sure what part of the code in particular is pushing it up to 13MB but this is semi-reasonable usage for a PHP script handling large files.  Your memory limit is also per-instance, it doesn't count all of your scripts running at once.  Using a profiler like Zend_Debugger or XDebug can help profile memory usage and maybe you can see an opportunity to reduce some memory usage.

Comment: Hm thats interesting. Ok so now i have a question. In my cpanel it says that right now im using Memory Usage 0 / 1048576 KB. In my php.ini i set the memory_limit to 256 MB. Im guessing my cpanel memory is the overall and thats where the 13 MB is showing up and if i allow my max upload size to be 256 MB if at least 4 people at the same time upload and choose encryption for a file that size what will happen. My download script uses no memory at all when it decrypts.

Comment: Your memory usage should still remain low even if someone uploads a large file because PHP doesn't keep the whole file in memory as it receives it.  And as long as your code doesn't read the whole file into memory at once and only reads it in small pieces, it should be fine.  You can increase or decrease the read size from `4096`.  Side effect of increasing is faster encryption, but more memory usage across many scripts at once.  Side effect of smaller read size is less memory usage but more reading and possibly slower encryption.

Comment: I manage a WHM/cPanel server and haven't seen that feature yet so I wasn't aware of that but I suspect you would have to have a large number of concurrent uploads going to hit that 1GB limit.  Try uploading a big file (500+ MB) and watch the memory usage while it uploads.  I guess it should stay fairly constant at some value.  You can then divide 1GB by that number and get a rough idea of the # of concurrent users you can support.

Comment: Hi, The memory usage only happens when it finished the upload and when it starts encrypting. Here is a picture of cpanel. http://stratus.sylentec.com/d152b8 (That url is the file sharing site that im building.

Comment: I see I guess you have a VPS which is why you get the memory usage displayed.  There is probably some latency between actual memory usage and seeing it in cPanel.  If your file sharing site gets popular enough, you'll probably have to move to a dedicated server anyway.

Comment: Hmm, Its shared hosting from mid phase im not sure if they use VPS, if they do that would be cool but if i use your above code and have the limit at 256 MB for uploads i should be good? It would be cool if you tried it out http://stratus.sylentec.com

Comment: Looks pretty cool, upload was smooth.  I started making an anti-leech / download interface, the code is on [github](https://github.com/dapphp/palantileech), and you can see a test file [here](https://revival.itsmyns.com/downloads/test.html).  never ended up going super far besides getting it working with a few features.  good luck with your site looks good.

Comment: thank you ive been working on it for a while, i also took a look at your project and it is interesting. to stay on topic i still havent solved this problem, it is driving me crazy any suggestions

Comment: Is the memory usage high again?  I'd say if it were still using around 13MB max that's pretty good.  At the end of your script, try logging the value of `memory_get_peak_usage(true);` to a file and that will tell you the peak real memory usage of the PHP script which is the most memory it consumed at one point in time.

Comment: @CristianRivera  See my edit, I had good results with the edited code.

Comment: @drew010 your code was very helpful but it didn't work for me until I added `rewind($my_file);` just before the while loop.

Comment: @Mm thanks for the comment, I modified the code to add the rewind in case anyone else is affected the same way.  It seems like it would be necessary so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: fwiw i tested stream_copy_to_stream memory usage in php7.3, and it use less than 2MB RAM to copy 1024 GB ram with https://paste.debian.net/plain/1276382